# What are some important (discrete) theorems involving (abstract) simplicial complexes

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex

I am interested in looking for some (preferably discrete) theorems involving simplicial complexes.

To elaborate, by discrete I mean the opposite of continuous, which are those theorems relating to continuous maps/topological spaces.

Most books I read introduce simplicial complexes as a means to do simplicial homology etc, hence they don't have many theorems devoted to simplicial complexes themselves.

Thanks. Pointing to a reference will be great too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many theorems "devoted to (abstract) simplicial complexes". Here are a few examples:

1. The [Kruskal–Katona theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Katona_theorem), characterising $f$-vectors of simplicial complexes.
2. The [Alexander duality](http://www.math.ku.dk/~moller/students/jens_jakob_kjaer_bach.pdf) for simplicial complexes.
3. [Stokes Theorem](https://cuhkmath.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/stokes-theorem-on-a-simplicial-complex/) for simplicial complexes.
4. [de Rham's Theorem](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4614-8468-4_9) for Simplicial Complexes.
5. [Erdős-Ko-Rado Theorem](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1001.0313) for Simplicial Complexes.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a lot.

Comment: @yoyostein You are welcome!