# Simplicial Stokes theorem

Tags: homology-cohomology, stokes-theorem, simplicial-complex

I have been intrested lately in a simplicial version of Stokes theorem, which intuitively I think should be true in simplicial settings.

I think if $X$ is a simplicial complex and $X(k)$ are its $k$-cells, I think something along the lines of

$$  \int_\Omega d\alpha  =\int_{d\Omega} \alpha ,$$

should be true, where $\alpha$ is  an anti-symmetric  map $\alpha:X(k)\to \mathbb{F}$ and $d$ is the co-boundary map, and $\mathbb{F}$ is an appropriate field.  I have so far been unsucsessful in finding such a result and was wondering whether someone has found an appropriate result.

I have however found [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2347090/what-are-some-important-discrete-theorems-involving-abstract-simplicial-comp) on the website which refers to [this result](https://cuhkmath.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/stokes-theorem-on-a-simplicial-complex/). But this seems to be adressing co-homology in a way which I am not sure is equivalent to how I described as anti-symmetric maps from $k$-cells. Also the other issue is that I am not sure whether this result is indeed valid, since I am myself not that comfortable with co-homology.

I will give some further context and say that I am interested in such result to give bounds on norms of elements of the form $d\alpha$.

I would appreciate any helpful remarks regarding any step of the points I've asked about.